Looking for Composition Differences in a Multi-Year Dataset
I have a multi-year dataset in which I am interested in a genotype (which I can code as a factor) over time for a particular species. I am interested in if there are significant differences in genotype composition between years. Visually, it looks like there should be, but I've been struggling to figure out the best way to model it. Here is a truncated example:



Year
Geno1
Geno2
Geno3
Geno4
Geno5




Year1
19
5
0
0
0


Year 2
25
3
3
1
0


Year 3
40
2
7
3
0


Year 4
3
3
18
5
0


Year 5
2
0
20
4
3


Year 6
1
0
19
3
6



What I've done in the past is just done a Pearson's chi-squared test which works well enough when I just want to make the case that there are clear composition differences. But I want to test whether the trends I'm seeing in the data are significant. I suspect I do need some kind of permutation test but I'm just at a loss for which one.
